# How to release resources used by HttpPostedFileBase?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After I upload a file I try to delete it from my PC but it is saying that the file is in use.

What code am I missing to free the file to be deletable?

Comment: If the request has completed, you should not have to do anything.  Perhaps some other process is locking it?

Comment: As Jim Counts says as you are uploading, even if you are uploading to IIS or casini on localhost, once the upload is complete, again even if you are debugging, the file has been read and transferred to the server.  I suggest using something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what is holding a lock on the file.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to close the InputStream manually after you read it to ensure that it is not held open until the HttpPostedFileBase is garbage collected.